# flutter: Is there any package work like web text editor which can pass the ui format from back end to front end by using api?

Tags: flutter

I used easy_web_view & html_editor to transfer the data html format data from back end to front end by using api. However, it seems not working with flutter when using HtmlElementView as content of html data will always refresh.

Therefore, i want to know is there package widget builder like html text editor which can edit the ui (EG: image, video, table, text size)

Html Issue link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53253

Comment: Not sure about the package, but you can create a simple `JSON` file and host it anywhere using simple HTTP get method you can call it and apply  theme UI and change UX  according to that

Comment: Thanks your comment, sorry for my bad english, but i want to know is there an editor like html editor which can let user to build the ui widget.

Comment: Frankly I have no idea about that.